# MYSQL Syntax Error on UPDATE with 'Key' word

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I simply cannot get my head around this one.

I am writing a simple PHP script to update a specific database field.

This query works fine, no problems at all, however setting_id is liable to change it seems and so is not suitable/portable

```
mysql_query("UPDATE oc_setting SET value='" . $css . "'" . 'WHERE setting_id=13576',    $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

This query, does not seem to work under any circumstances, which is the query I need.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE oc_setting SET value='" . $css . "'" . 'WHERE key="sellya_custom_css"', $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

It leaves me this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key="sellya_custom_css"' at line 1

Now I had a hunch it may have something with the word key perhaps being a reserved keyword or something so I tried wrapping it in quotes, and while the script did not come up with any errors, it did not update the field either.

I have tried countless of combinations with single quotes double quotes, concatenation combinations of various sorts to no avail.

Could someone please help me out here?

Thank you.

Comment: `key` is a reserved word and should have back ticks if you still want to use it

Comment: Why did I receive a down vote :S?

Comment: theres no wrong with this question.

Comment: Sorry, no clue. I didn't down vote. but a down vote is  understandable since you are yourself saying it might be a problem with reserved words, but you didn't search Google for what to do when you have to use a reserved word in a query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KEY` is a reserve word in mysql

better put  `KEY` inside `` back ticks.

Source([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html))

Comment: perfect thank you! I thought that might be the case, but I was not aware that I had to use special quotes (``) to wrap it.

Comment: @user1650757 yes it perfectly good to practice having it.. :D

Comment: you should be referencing partitioning key but instead the list of reserved keywords in mysql. [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 2):

> [Please, don't use `mysql_*`
>   functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code.
>   They are no longer maintained and are [officially
>   deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red
>   box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) or
>   [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli).

Now, to the question:

```
"UPDATE oc_setting SET value='" . $css . "'" . 'WHERE key="sellya_custom_css"'
```

in this query string, you are missing a space before `WHERE`. Change it to:

```
"UPDATE oc_setting SET value='" . $css . "'" . ' WHERE `key`="sellya_custom_css"'
```

---

**`key`** needs to be escaped in the query too.

Comment: Ok ill take the time to look into pdo and mysqli, after adding the space, I am still getting the same error.